# what would be a quick way to check if $f(x)=\frac{x \cdot (x^4+1)\cdot (x+1)+x^4+2}{x^2+x+1}$ for $~f:R \to R$ is onto/into and many one/one-one.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

f'(x) looks painful for checking surjectivity. And for $~~f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ to determine injectivity, also doesn't look very nice, I'm thinking there should be a noticeable manipulation of the function into something very prominent. But I haven't been able to notice yet.

Comment: Note that you’re actually dealing with $$(x^4+1)+\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$.

Comment: how did you observe this?

Comment: Well, there’s a factor of $x^4+1$ in one of the terms in the numerator, so I separate $x^4+1$ from the leftover $x^4+2$ and found that it gives ($x^4+1)(x^2+x+1)$. Or you could be looking at the $x(x+1)=x^2+x$ term and be thinking that adding another ($x^4+1$) to it would cancel the denominator.

Comment: Very quick way to check for non-injectivity is $f$ continuous (as denominator has no real root) and $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=\frac 73>2$ and $f(\frac 12)=\frac{183}{112}<2$ so we are in a case $\searrow\nearrow$.

Comment: The denominator is always positive.  The numerator is a 6th-degree polynomial so it goes to plus infinity as $x$ goes to plus and minus infinity.  Which means your function does the same thing.  It's not onto because it's never negative and it's not 1-1 because the graph is eventually a $U$ shape.

Comment: Including $-\infty$ and $\infty$ as "asymptotes" (they aren't really, but it makes this rule easier), a simplified rational function will be surjective if between some adjacent pair of asymptotes, there are an odd number of zeros of the numerator, counted by multiplicity. If not, and all zeros of the denominator are of even multiplicty (as here, since there are no zeros of the denominator), the function is not surjective. If there is a denominator zero of odd multiplicity, you have to check extrema between the asymptotes to figure it out.